# Spring-hibernate Data Insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to insert Data into table using HibernateTemplate but so far no luck.

here is code -

```
Catch
```

else

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at        com.imall.service.registrationService.regUser(registrationService.java:29)
    at com.imall.web.LoginController.registerUser(LoginController.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And Here is applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">  </property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>        
 </bean> 
  <bean id="sessionFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"></property>
     <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/imall/pojo/User.hbm.xml</value>  
            <value>com/imall/pojo/regUser.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>  
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
      </property>
 </bean>
 <bean id="hibernateTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean"></property>
 </bean>
  <bean id="authenticateServiceBean"   class="com.imall.service.AuthticateService">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplateBean">   </property>
  </bean> 
    <bean id="registrationServiceBean"    class="com.imall.service.registrationService">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplateBean">    </property>
    </bean> 
 </beans>
```

Here is the Service Method-

```
public class registrationService {

private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public registrationService() 
{
}
public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
}

public boolean regUser(com.imall.pojo.regUser rgUser)
{
    System.out.println(rgUser.getfName());
    try
    {
        System.out.println("in try--"+rgUser.getEmailId());
        hibernateTemplate.save(rgUser);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Catch");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Here are the other code -

LoginController Method-

```
@Autowired
private registrationService regService;

@RequestMapping(value="/register.php",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute("regDetails") regUser userReg)
{
    System.out.println(userReg.getfName());

    if(regService.regUser(userReg))
        {
            System.out.println("IF");
            return new ModelAndView("success");
        }
    else
        {
            System.out.println("else");
            return new ModelAndView("success"); 
        }

}
```

The line 29 in RegistrationService is- `hibernateTemplate.save(rgUser);`

And this line  `System.out.println(rgUser.getfName());` is printing the name.

Comment: Which line is `registrationService.java:29` ? also you should read about naming conventions. Classnames should start with uppercase character

Comment: have you checked your rgUser object? ,ay be it is null

Comment: Don't create a new instance of the `RegistationService` in your `LoginController`, use the spring created one.

Comment: like other people said... rgUser might be null... have you tried debugging? what value does rgUser have?

Comment: Can you comment and let us know which line is throwing NPE. Also, make sure all your beans are injected by string. LIke @M.Deinum said avoid using `new` operator.

Comment: can you post the code that invokes the service? your bean/controller

Comment: @M.Deinum How to use the one that Spring created. And I have added the controller code above. – And during debugging, all the values are passed to regUser and all have values except userId which is 0. And in Db my userId is auto incremental.

Comment: Is your registration service annotated with `@Service`?

Comment: No. And what is the use?